# Error while updating Google Repository

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

My internet is working fine still I am getting the error. Please see the pic below for error.

[image]

It is saying Please check Installation log. I can't find where is installation log and how to solve the problem.

Please help.

Comment: did you try restarting android studio?

Comment: but you error is 404,the "package" not found

Comment: Restarting doesn't worked for me. Same error again

Comment: one moment, i have te similar error in this moment **404 not found**,maybe is general the error